# How to publish results of meteor method?

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications

Collection1 - user private details
Collection2 - user public info

I have a requirement where a user sets specific search criteria  as object and sends it to server through Meteor.call

```
Meteor.call('userQuery',getSearchBoxdata(),function(err,data){
              if(err){
                console.log(err);
              }else{
                console.log(data);
                _.each(data,function(mark){
                    dosomeThing(mark);
                  });
                }
            });
```

on Server side

```
    Meteor.methods({
      userQuery:function(post){
      //map functions to calculate _ids matching the query
      return Collection1.find({
           _id: {$in: ids}
            }, {
        fields: {
            "gender": 1,
            "mobile": 1,
            "location": 1
            }
       })
    }
```

How can we introduce reactivity here, so that we get updated results when new users satisfy the query.

Comment: Your main issue in this code is the server-side `_id` mapping part. If you want reactivity, then your best bet is using a publication (they are built for this very purpose). Methods are rather used for things that do not need to be reactive. But since you map the `_id`s via functions calls, it won't be any kind of reactive. From here I can somewhat imagine using a Collection query with `observeChanges` and special callbacks with `this.added` and co in your publication to handle it, but it suggests you use a Col to map. How do you do this mapping? More specifically, what data do you use for it?

Comment: the `_id` is calculated as a result of two aggregation functions on user preference data and a map function to filter results based on a logic. So it is not a simple collection query